# Ghidra is mishandling a field access

Tags: windows, decompilation, ghidra

I have a program which decompiles in Ghidra to include the line

```
temp_5f2f2f81bc = *(CPedIntelligence **)(&DAT_000010c0 + (longlong)pCVar2);
```

`temp_5f2f2f81bc` is a `CPedIntelligence*`. `pCVar2` is a `CPed*`, and `CPed` has a `CPedIntelligence*` located at offset `0x10c0`. So this *should* decompile as `temp_5f2f2f81bc = pCVar2->intelligence;`. Is there a way to tell Ghidra "no, `pCVar2` should not be cast to longlong?"

I've noticed this occurring other times as well, and it generally seems to be associated with a structure stored in a register (here, `pCVar2` is stored in `R13`). In the function's local variables, though, `pCVar2` is listed as being stored in `HASH:5f32eb8...` The register is never used in the function *except* as the storage for this `CPed*`, so if I could forcibly tell the decompiler "this register has this type throughout the entire function" then that'd help. I tried using scripting to create a local variable stored in `R13`, but the decompiler didn't pick up on it.